# Present subjunctive after 'until'?

Tags: grammar

I consulted https://english.stackexchange.com/a/7823/50720, but when's the present subjective (call this PS) used after 'until'? Only in the past? Am I right in guessing that do here is conjugated in the PS?

> 1. Till death do us part. => **Until** death do + **part us** => Until death do (instead of `does`) part us.

Answer (score 4):

The present subjunctive was formerly used in clauses beginning with 'until'. It is not so used in modern English. The auxiliary verb 'do' was formerly not uncommon in non-emphatic affirmative present and past simple firms, indicative and subjunctive. It is not so used in modern English.

Comment: +1 This phrase derives from the revised *Book of Common Prayer* of 1662, and the 'subjunctive' *do* goes back to the original edition of 1549.

Comment: Please don’t mind my edit for want of clarity, but please feel free to edit it or advise me if offensive.

Comment: The terms 'auxiliary DO' and 'dummy DO' (without a preceding 'the verb') are  not uncommon in books and articles on the subject.